Question about protect global extern variable
I want to using this variable globally (C,C++)
config.h
extern YAML::Node m_configList
config.cpp
YAML::Node m_configList;
this is yaml-cpp variable.
this variable using 3 files
file1.cpp
file2.cpp
main.cpp
Do I protect this variable using mutex or etc..?
If I protect this variable, Do I protect this with global extern mutex variable?

"I want to use this variable globally" NO : First step is to avoid global variables completely.
Wrap all your code in a class with setter functions and instantiate that class in main. Then pass it (or its abstract baseclass) to the code that need acces to it. With the setter function you can handle multithreading by giving the wrapper class a mutex (or more). Also read a bit more about dependency injection and how it avoids the need for "global" state.

Using a mutex (or something similar) is only needed when you use multiple threads.

You only need to protect it with a mutex if it may be accessed by different execution threads. If you need to access the variable from C-modules you need to define it in a C-compatible way (or use C-compatible access functions).

Does this answer your question? To Mutex or Not To Mutex?

@Pepijn Kramer
I think that this way is the good way... thank you
As I tried to use the variable globally, I was concerned about this variable being
invaded by other threads.

@Kundera Global variables will get out of control (even without threads). In larger projects you cannot defend against other developer just changing that variable because the have "accidental access" to it by just including a header file.

You should really watch Value Semantics: Safety, Independence, Projection, & Future of Programming - Dave Abrahams CppCon 22 on why having global variables (or references to variables) in your code can get uncontrollable.

"this way is the good way" it's not. There is a mountain of material telling you exactly why, go read them.

If you need to protect it. that's a reason for not making it global at all. You would have to make it private and write a getter and setter that did the protecting. IOW your question doesn't actually make sense..

The use of global variables is debatable (as comments show). While it is good practice to avoid global variables, there are cases, mostly in smaller projects where they may make sense.
One case where a global variable should almost certainly be avoided is if it may be accessed by more than one thread. In that case, the variable must be protected by a mutex. Since a mutex must be managed carefully to avoid concurrency issues, the mutex and thus the access to the variable must be centralized to ensure that the variable is only accessed with the mutex locked and to ensure that the mutex is always unlocked after use.
Hence, neither the variable nor the mutex should be global.
A simplified example (no error checks and only supporting string values) could be as follows:
config.h:
   ...
   // Config access functions
   std::string getConfig(const std::string key);
   void setConfig(const std::string key, const std::string value);

config.cpp:
   ...
   static YAML::Node configList;  // Keep variables private to the config module
   static std::mutex configMutex;

   std::string getConfig(const std::string key)
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(configMutex);
      return configList[key];
   }

   void setConfig(const std::string key, const std::string value)
   {
      std::lock_guard<std::mutex>(configMutex);
      configList[key] = value;
   }


"mostly in smaller projects where they make sense" citation needed.

@PasserBy Changed to "where they may make sense". This is based on many years of personal experience, not a written reference. Software development is not black/white. There is always a tradeoff between resources and the ideal solution.
